# Xdebug 3 not included in phpinfo()

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

I have a problem with Xdebug on Mac OS using Big Sur. Below, I will explain what is happening.

1. When I run `phpinfo()` - I don't see a Xdebug section at all.
2. When I run commands such as `xdebug_call_file()` it throws a `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function` error.

---

Here are all the configurations:

`php -v`:

[image]

PhpStorm shows that Debugger is active:

[image]

`php.ini` (/usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php.ini) has these configurations:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port="9003"
```

PhpStorm is not detecting Xdebug to set the interpreter:

[image]

Does anyone know what might be the issues with Xdebug not showing up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you will get when `develop` is not part of the `xdebug.mode` setting is:

> Warning: Function must be enabled in php.ini by setting 'xdebug.mode' to 'develop'

As you get the "Call to undefined function" error, that means that Xdebug is not loaded in your web server environment. It is often that the web server environment has a different INI file.

In order to see if Xdebug is loaded, and which INI files PHP has read, you can use use `phpinfo()` in a PHP script **requested through a browser**. This will also show whether Xdebug is loaded. If it does, you can use `xdebug_info()` to check its settings.

PhpStorm's "Interpreter Check" also only checks the command line, and not the web server version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

> `develop`: Enables Development Helpers including the overloaded var_dump(). https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode

`xdebug.mode=debug,develop`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but it looks like it doesn't do much, unless php/nginx/apache have to be restarted after updating php.ini

Comment: @user17997251 it's right solution, restart http server

Comment: This is not the right answer, as the error message is different if `develop` isn't part of the `xdebug.mode` settings.